# Kotlin android extensions in custom view with databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-extension

I have a Custom Linear layout and an xml file in with 3 checkboxes. The Custom linear layout looks roughly like this:

```
class AdvancedBox : LinearLayout, DefineExchangesDialog.DefineExchangesDialogListener {

    private lateinit var mBinding: AdvancedBoxBinding

    private lateinit var viewModel: GlobalConfigViewModel

    constructor(c: Context) : super(c) {
        initLayout()
    }

    constructor(c: Context, a: AttributeSet) : super(c, a) {
        initLayout()
    }

    private fun initLayout() {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mBinding = AdvancedBoxBinding.inflate(inflater)
    }

    override fun getRootView(): View {
        return mBinding.root
    }

    fun setViewModel(viewModel: GlobalConfigViewModel){
        mBinding.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()

        //cbVolumeChange is an id defined in advanced_box.xml 
        cbVolumeChange.setOnClickListener(this::onShowAdvanced)
        cbExchanges.setOnClickListener(this::onShowAdvanced)
        cbPriceFilter.setOnClickListener(this::onShowAdvanced)
    }
```

The problem is that setting an onClickListener on any of the checkboxes in onFinishInflate() will cause a NullPointerException. I thought overriding the getRootView() would be the solution but that did not work. Something that would work is the following

```
val root = mBinding.root
root.cbVolumeChange ...
```

But that is not something I would like to do. So what would be the right way to use the Android Kotlin extension with databinding in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that the inflated view is not attached to the layout. You should use `AdvancedBoxBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true)` for it.

After that `onFinishInflate()` doesn't matter for you, as it's only relevant for inflating the view and the hierarchy from XML not from code as you're doing.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much for the explanation :)